# Cannot use polish letters in RoR application

Tags: oracle, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord, oci8

I have problem when I trying to insert object to database.
Looks like it's convertion problem. Is there a way to fix this?

```
   I, [2017-10-28T14:02:19.923386 #56398]  INFO -- : [49eba256-de7f-48df-8d00-05148a6495d3] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 286ms (ActiveRecord: 9.5ms)
F, [2017-10-28T14:02:19.925305 #56398] FATAL -- : [49eba256-de7f-48df-8d00-05148a6495d3]
F, [2017-10-28T14:02:19.925557 #56398] FATAL -- : [49eba256-de7f-48df-8d00-05148a6495d3] ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: U+0142 from UTF-8 to US-ASCII: INSERT INTO "RECIPE_INGREDIENTS" ("QUANTITY", "RECIPE_ID", "INGREDIENT_ID", "CREATED_AT", "UPDATED_AT", "ID") VALUES (:a1, :a2, :a3, :a4, :a5, :a6)):
F, [2017-10-28T14:02:19.925663 #56398] FATAL -- : [49eba256-de7f-48df-8d00-05148a6495d3]
```

This happens only when I using polish characters like ł, ą, ć

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It rather looks as if your underlying database is configured with a US7ASCII characterset which doesn't support UTF8 characters, but your application is a UTF8 application. You'll likely need to work with the DBA team to get a database with AL32UTF8 or similar character set.